# What is called an organization where people are looking for a job for a while?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, proper-nouns, names

I am writing a CV in English and I have come to work experience.

*I do not know if there is a name in English for this organization or something like that, but in my language a literal translation would be a youth co-operative.*

It is an organization/place where mostly students come, let's say the most over the summer or people who cannot find a job in another way. Then, when they get and finish a job, this organization takes a percentage for themselves, and the rest gives the worker.

Comment: This might be culturally specific. I'm not sure a similar organisation exists in the UK.  Which country is this?  Is there a website or wikipedija article about these cooperatives?

Comment: @JamesK I am from Serbia. this is Wikipedia article https://sr.wikipedia.org/sr-el/Omladinska_zadruga, but no English translation :( If there is no something similar in UK, what could I call it? Youth organization?

Comment: This kind of thing http://www.ozbulevar.rs/index.php?oglas=2308

Answer (score 1):

Such a system does not exist in exactly this form in the UK.

There are "Job agencies", "Employment agencies" and "Temping agencies". These either find workers to fill particular jobs (in return for a "finders fee") or will act as an employer for temporary staff. So if a company needs an office worker, they can get a "temp" from the "temping agency". The company pays the agency and the agency pays the worker.

In teaching such agencies are known as "supply agencies", and in medicine they are called "Locum agencies" (a locum is a doctor working on a temporary contract).

So you could say

> I was employed as a temporary *office worker* through a job agency *'Name of Agency'*.

The alternative is to translate literally

> I was a member of the *Belgrade Youth Cooperative* and worked through the cooperative as a temporary *packer at a food factory*.

By using capitals I show that this is "the thing named the Belgrade Youth Cooperative" and so warning the reader that the words might have a specific meaning.

Comment: The US equivalent is "employment agency". However, such agencies operate year-round.